# Why is the maximum size of the call stack exceeded when I traverse my tree?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am trying to get the minimum value from my binary tree but I am getting an error that the maximum call stack size was exceeded. How do I correctly get the minimum value of items in a binary search tree?

Here is my code at [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/mayozujuva/edit?html,js,output):

```
function Node(val){
    this.value = val;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}

function BinarySearchTree(){
    this.root = null;
}
BinarySearchTree.prototype.minNode =function() {
    var node = this.root;
    if(!node){
        return 0;
    }
    if(node.left){
        return this.minNode(node.left)
    }
    return node.value
}

BinarySearchTree.prototype.push = function(val){
    var root = this.root;

    if(!root){
        this.root = new Node(val);
        return;
    }

    var currentNode = root;
    var newNode = new Node(val);

    while(currentNode){
        if(val < currentNode.value){
            if(!currentNode.left){
                currentNode.left = newNode;
                break;
            }
            else{
                currentNode = currentNode.left;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(!currentNode.right){
                currentNode.right = newNode;
                break;
            }
            else{
                currentNode = currentNode.right;
            }
        }
    }

}

var bt = new BinarySearchTree();
bt.push(23);
bt.push(1);
bt.push(2);
bt.push(25);
console.log(bt.minNode());
```

Comment: You are not advancing `node`. You set it to the root on every recurse.

Comment: is it not current ? what is the correct way .t get minimum value

Comment: You either need to pass it as a parameter to the recursive method, or you need to keep a `.currentSearchNode` property on the instance and use that instead of `this.root` so you can keep track of where you're at. Note that this can *still* overflow the stack easily for any meaningful dataset. JavaScript isn't great at handling direct recursion. You can always trampoline thunks instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @AndrewLi mentioned. You are setting the same root again, by writing

```
var node = this.root;
```

Instead change the definition of your function

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.minNode =function(nextNode) {
    var node = nextNode || this.root;
    if(!node){
        return 0;
    }
    if(node.left){
        return this.minNode(node.left)
    }
    return node.value
}
```

Comment: Yes I was also thinking about the same. But credits shoud go to you since you responsed first in the comment

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not advancing the node when you traverse it. You just keep on setting `node` to the root element, thus it recurses forever. Defining the function like so should work:

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.minNode = function(nextNode) {
  var node = nextNode || this.root;
  if(!node) {
    return 0;
  }
  if(node.left) {
    return this.minNode(node.left)
  }
  return node.value
}
```

This will make the function accept an argument for the *next node*. Then it will assign `node` to the next node if it exists, or the root if it's the first call. This will not recurse forever because it advances and traverses the tree.